# What is the best way to make two different apps work together? (React.js and JSP)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jsp, backend, single-page-application

1. I have React.js (not SSR just SPA) app on Frontend, Node.js app on Backend.
2. I have payment page (on React).
3. I have Payment module written on JSP.

What i need to develop:

1. On payment page i select the subscription plan.
2. After that Payment JSP page opening with selected subscription plan price.

What is the best way to make two different apps work together?

Comment: I would consider Microfrontends integration (via iframe, web components...)

Answer (score 0):

One of the way will be redirecting your user from one project to another.